# How to insert a new column with repeated values into a pandas table?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python. I have scraped a html table by pandas and I'm looking for ways to insert a new column with repeated string value and set it as the index of the table (as follow:). Reminded that the table is a long one :).

Original df:

```
Age IQ
12  100
15  111
 .   .
 .   .
 .   .
 .   .
13  121
```

Expected df"

```
Group  Age IQ
 A     12  100
 A     15  111
 .      .   .
 .      .   .
 .      .   .
 .      .   .
 A     13  121
```

Answer (score 16):

Use [**`assign`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a copy of your dataframe with a new column included:

```
df.assign(Group='A')

   Age   IQ Group
0   12  100     A
1   15  111     A
2   13  121     A
```

You can realign the columns afterwards

```
df.assign(Group='A')[['Group'] + df.columns.tolist()]

  Group  Age   IQ
0     A   12  100
1     A   15  111
2     A   13  121
```

---

However, you can edit the dataframe in place with [**`insert`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html).  This has the added bonus of allowing you to specify where the new column goes.

```
df.insert(0, 'Group', 'A')

df

  Group  Age   IQ
0     A   12  100
1     A   15  111
2     A   13  121
```